# Finding the IP address of a domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I find the IP address of an arbitrary domain? I want to get the IP address from the DNS server.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
require 'socket'
IPSocket::getaddress('www.google.com') #=> "74.125.79.147"
```

Answer (score 13):

Resolv is on a higher level than Socket, so will use more resources. However it has the ability to find all the ip addresses of a domain

```
require 'resolv'
Resolv.getaddresses("www.ruby-lang.org")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try going through the shell

```
domain = "google.com"
`host #{domain}`.match(/(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/).to_s
#=> "74.125.39.99"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
require 'resolv'
puts Resolv.getaddresses("www.panfu.dk")
```

Answer (score 0):

you always can enter http://who.is/ and enter the url of the ip you're seeking for

Answer (score -4):

This is the  java script code which will retrun the client's IP as json object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function knowYourIP(json){
  document.write(json.ip); 
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=knowYourIP"></script>
```

Comment: -1 OP was not looking for client address, but for a way to look up the IP of an arbitrary domain.

Comment: okies, i misunderstood the question. but can't we get it thru like ping www.google.com?

Comment: OP wanted a Ruby answer, he got a Ruby answer and it was accepted. :-)