# Detect redirect to specific IP with Mechanize Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, mechanize

I am using the Ruby Mechanize Gem in to fetch and parse websites and I need to detect redirects to a certain IP. Here is my basic setup:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.example.com')
```

Now, its obvious how to detect the redirect as such:

```
is_redirect? = page.code[/30[12]/].present?
```

but I want to take it a step further and check what domain/IP it redirects to; so something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
if page.resolves_to(55.55.55.55)...
```

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the IP address of a domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742521/finding-the-ip-address-of-a-domain)

Comment: @D-side: This question is not about finding the IP but checking the final destination of a redirect via its IP.

Comment: I did manage to detect a redirection IP for `mail.google.com`, but it responds with code `200` and a `<meta>` redirect. I started writing up an answer but then I thought you might get redirects differently. Is there a live example of a redirect you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

The redirected url is in `Page#uri`:

```
require 'socket'
IPSocket::getaddress(page.uri.host)
```